# Expected number of buckets filled when placing $N$ balls such that no $2$ adjacent buckets can be filled?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

You have $N$ buckets and $N$ balls. What is the the expected number of filled buckets such that no $2$ adjacent buckets can be simultaneously filled? "Filled" here means the bucket has exactly $1$ ball. Each ball is placed in a non-adjacent random bucket one after the other.

First assume the buckets are arranged in a line. Next assume the buckets are arranged in a circle (basically the same as the line except the ends are now connected to each other).

I am totally lost on how to solve this problem. I wrote out a recursion, but it is very messy, and I don't think that's the right approach, nor do I know how to solve it and get a closed expression. I also tried finding a solution for a few small $N$'s to see if I could identify a pattern and try induction, but no luck.

Is there some trick that makes this problem simple/simpler?

Here is an example for the case where the buckets are arranged in a line. Consider $n=5$. If the first ball is placed in bucket $1$, then the second ball will either be placed in bucket $3,4,5$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. If the second ball is placed in the $3$rd bucket, then the $3$rd ball will be placed in the $5$th bucket.

Now consider the buckets arranged in a circle. So now bucket $1$ and $5$ are adjacent to each other. So the only possible ways to fill the buckets are filling buckets $(1,3)$, $(1,4)$, $(2,4)$, $(2,5)$, $(3,5)$.

---

I'm going to write out some basic work that I did. Consider the circular case. Let $S_N$ be a random variable denoting the number of filled buckets starting with $N$ empty buckets. The first ball can be placed in any of the $N$ buckets with probability $\frac{1}{N}$.

From the law of total expectation, and using $A_i$ to denote the event that the i-th bucket is chosen for the first ball, we have
$$
E[S_N] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E[S_N | A_i] P(A_i) \\
$$

By symmetry, we know $E[S_N | A_i] = E[S_N | A_j] \ \ \forall i,j$. Thus,
$$
E[S_N] = E[S_N | A_1] = \ldots = E[S_N | A_N] \\
$$

Further, after placing the first ball in the i-th bucket, we have $N-3$ choices for the placement of the next ball. Based on this, I was originally (wrongly) thinking that the following is true:
$$
E[S_N | A_1] = 1 + E[S_{N-3}]
$$

However, this is not correct because I have defined $S_N$ to be the random variable for the number of filled buckets where the original $N$ empty buckets are arranged circularly. When we place the first ball, we are left with $N-3$ buckets, but the $N-3$ buckets are not arranged circularly. They are effectively arranged linearly. So we introduce $L_i$ to be the number of filled buckets when starting out with $i$ empty buckets arranged linearly.

Then we can write
$$
E[S_N | A_1] = E[L_{N-3}] \\
E[S_N] = 1 + E[L_{N-3}]
$$

Based on this and using this approach, it seems the circular problem is coupled to the linear problem.

Note that I have disregarded the number of balls remaining (or the number of balls available to be placed for a given number of empty buckets) because it is guaranteed that we will run out of available buckets before we run out of balls.

---

Now consider the linear case. The law of total expectation yields the same equation
$$
E[L_N] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E[L_N | A_i] P(A_i) \\
$$

But now, a symmetry argument for $E[L_N | A_i]$ no longer holds. If the first ball is placed in the i-th bucket, then we have 2 subproblems to recurse on. The valid buckets to the left and right of the i-th bucket. Specifically we have $\max(0, i - 2)$ valid buckets to the left and $\max(0, N- i - 1)$ valid buckets to the right. Valid here means that the next ball is able to be placed in any of the buckets.

So
$$
E[L_N | A_i] = 1 + E[L_{\max(0,i - 2)}] + E[L_{\max(0, n - i - 1)}]
$$

and
$$
E[L_N] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} (1 + E[L_{\max(0,i - 2)}] + E[L_{\max(0, n - i - 1)}]) P(A_i) \\
= 1 + P(A_1)\sum_{i=1}^{N} E[L_{\max(0,i - 2)}] + E[L_{\max(0, n - i - 1)}]
$$

We have the following boundary condition: $L_0 = 0$.

Comment: Do you mean:  if the first ball goes in bucket $\#2$ then buckets $\#1$ and $\#3$ can never get a ball?

Comment: @lulu Right. I'm going to edit in some examples to make this clearer.

Comment: And explain what "filled" means.

Comment: How many balls does it take to fill a bucket?

Comment: @herbsteinberg 1

Comment: So "filled" means "exactly one ball"?  Then at least you get a recursion, no?  For the linear case I mean.  If the first ball goes into slot $i$ with $1<i<n$ then you are down to the case of $n-2$ and $n-i-1$.  This won't instantly get you a closed formula, but it should make it easy to compute lots and lots of cases.  And of course the circular case with $n$ elements is $1$ greater than the linear case with $n-3$ elements.

Comment: To get a better recursion I would note that exactly one of slots $n$ and $n-1$ must get filled and I would try to calculate the probability that it is slot $n$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, filled means exactly one ball. And I think I was approaching it from a similar recursive way. Where $E[S_N] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N 1 + E[S_{i - 2}] + E[S_{N - i - 1}]$, where $S_N$ is the number of filled buckets among $N$ buckets. (This is for the linear case)

Comment: @lulu For the circular case. I believe $E[S_N] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N 1 + E[S_{n - 3}]$

Comment: Well you have to take care when the first toss goes into one of the buckets on the end, but otherwise, yes.  That's what I meant.  But I expect there is a better recursion to be had along the lines of a prior comment of mine.

Comment: For the circular case it makes no difference which bucket is chosen initially...you always get the same linear pattern afterwards.

Comment: @lulu How do you compute the probability that the last slot is filled for the linear case?

Comment: I have not worked that out.   Again, I would try to do it recursively.

Comment: I assume placement is by discretion.  I'm a little confused.  For the straight line case doesn't it mean filling every other bucket?  N even leads to N/2 while N odd leads to(N+1)/2.   Similarly for circle case.  Neven leads to same result, while N odd leads to (N-1)/2.

Comment: @lulu After some additional thinking, I think the circular case that I wrote above is wrong, which basically would have simplified to $E[S_N] = 1 + E[S_{n-3}]$. The issue is the $E[S_{n-3}]$ is the solution for n-3 linear buckets, and not n-3 circular buckets.

Comment: @herbsteinberg. That might be what the solution ultimately simplifies to. But it doesn't necessarily mean every other bucket is filled for the linear case. For example, consider $n=5$. A valid set of filled buckets is bucket 1 and 4.

Comment: @herbsteinberg  Consider the case of four linear buckets.  Then it is perfectly possible that the first ball goes in  $\#1$ and the second goes in $\#4$.

Comment: Does the person doing the filling have a choice other than not adjacent?  If not, what is the rule?  If random, is the distribution uniform?

Comment: Yes, it is random uniform. So for the linear case, with $n=5$ if the first random choice is the first bucket. Then the second random choice can be buckets 3,4,5, with probability $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: @herbsteinberg  As I understand it (and as the examples indicate)  the choices are uniformly random among the available options.  Thus if you have six linear buckets and the first one goes in $\#4$ the second can go in $1,2,6$ with equal probabilities.